# Inverter defect on Asus Laptop?

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, lcd, asus-laptop

My good old - but still in use - Asus V1S laptop has stopped working well. Display shows only a vertical green line on the left site. An attached external monitor works fine.

So my supposition (and hope) is that graphics card is fine but the inverter to the LCD is defective. Is this a likely theory, or are the chances for a defect in LCD/graphic card higher? Am I missing something? Anyone with better idea or experience which can support or rebut my "inverter-thesis"?

The backlight is still working.

Comment: I don't think it's the inverter, do you see anything else on the screen other than a green line? It could be the cable connecting your LCD to the motherboard or the LCD itself?

Comment: @Malcolm: Thanks for your comment. I see only a green line. No backlight. I will check the cable connections when backup is finished. Thanks so far for your good input.

Comment: @Micha it could be the bridge connection that connects your screens ribbon cable to your motherboard, i've had experience in the past where some have come loose or broken altogether from being dropped or similar reasons.

Comment: @RyanIG: Thanks for your feedback. The lapetop is meanwhile retired, so I can´t test your idea, but the idea is itself is good :) If you post is as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the ribbon cable which connects the monitor to your motherboard.

[image]

I've seen in the past some laptops where the cable has become lose or the bridge connection brakes altogether.

The bridge connector is small piece of plastic which snaps the ribbon cable into place, they can be quite flimsy and break easily if not held carefully.

[image]

There are tutorials online on how to fix this issue.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qljz6bxbSP0
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOE4T6nykQ4

This might not be the case but it would be by best guess.